# Nam-6 performance degrade

Tags: google-cloud-platform, latency, google-cloud-spanner

We were using `nam3` and recently switched to `nam6`, we are observing 200 to 250ms increase in query latency. i understand we have to take some burden on going across different machines and different regions. But ~250ms increase is too much. Our app cluster in east-us, do we have any recommendations to improve the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving from nam3 to nam6 changes your default leader region from us-east4 to us-central1 [1].  You may want to consider whether you can allow for greater read staleness or move your clients closer to us-central1.

"For optimal read performance outside of the default leader region, use staleness of at least 15 seconds." [2]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/instances#available-configurations-multi-region

[2] https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/instances#multi-region-best-practices

Comment: Thanks for the response, to your point 2, we tried with stale read with Node and Java both did not improve any response time. Some it increases the latency than reducing it

Comment: Also the insert and updates(mutations) are taking longer

Comment: @NareshNagarajan if you have access to GCP Support, this should be your primary avenue of getting assistance with environment-specific questions. Public forum is a suboptimal avenue for addressing it.